# OpenCV Image in Image Search (C++)

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I want to detect objects in a given "original Image", based on another "proposed Image". The "proposed Image" is  smaller than the original Image and it might not look 100% alike (background may differ slightly). I want to find all occurences of the "proposed Image" in the original Image.

Is there an efficient way to do this in OpenCV?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you may try [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html?highlight=template).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could train and run CascadeClassifier.
Another option is using 2d feature detectors and descriptors, for example SIFT.